# Fox Float CTD Evolution vs Fox Float CTD Performance

Tags: fork

What is the difference between Fox Float CTD Evolution and Fox Float CTD Performance? Except that one is most expensive and better? I mean real difference...

Answer (score 2):

What's actually increasing the cost in performance fork is it's construction qualitiy. It's slightly better in terms of durability and a bit lighter. Depending on the year of make, performance may also include a new technology or system that the evolution (which is the basic lineup) won't have (thus making it more expensive). Think fox's lineup as this:

evolution -> sunday family ride

performance -> more intense riding

factory -> pro riding

Answer (score 0):

Evolution is a very basic fork , 
The Performance is almost similar to the factory FIT. 
The Performance is much better ...

Comment: Could you expand on how it's better? In what way(s) specifically? More travel? More durable? More adjustable? Lighter? Etc.